# PHP MySQL search db hat contains using % Wildcard

Tags: php, mysql

I have looked up many responses on hear in regards to searching using `LIKE %` and also `CONCAT` but they are not working for me.
Basically I am trying to find in the database words like % `Croyden` and `Surrey`
The below script works fine, however I want to use % for words that contain `Croyden` and `Surrey`. I have tried various ways but nothing work.

```
$locTown = "Croydon";
$locCounty = "Surrey";

$query = 'SELECT locTown, locCounty FROM location where locTown LIKE ? AND locCounty LIKE ? ';

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query)) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $locTown, $locCounty);  

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $locTown, $locCounty);

    /* fetch value */
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

    }

    echo "Location: $locTown - $locCounty\n";

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

Just for Clarity the below now works correctly after updating SQL and the Fething result.

```
$query = "SELECT locTown, locCounty FROM location where locTown LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND locCounty LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') ";    

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query)) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $locTown, $locCounty);  

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $locTown, $locCounty);

    /* fetch value */
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);


    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

      echo "Location: $locTown - $locCounty\n";

    }


    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: example I tried LIKE CONCAT("%", ?, "%") in the Sql and tried this in variable $locTown = "%$Croydon%";

Comment: Hi, yes you are correct, the sql appears to be working, one thing however its not displaying all the results but only 1 result. Is the while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) { correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since concatenating `%` in the query didn't work for the OP, you can try concatenating the `%` when binding as an alternative:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", '%'.$locTown, '%'.$locCounty);
```

Comment: Hi, Sql workins correct now thants to you guys. I have also worked out why all the data was not displaying it was because I had echo "Location: $locTown - $locCounty\n";
 in the wrong place as it was after the   while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

    }